# Discrete Math logically equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that (p ∨ (q ∧ ¬r)) → p is logically equivalent to p ∨ ¬q ∨ r.

I'm hitting the dead end all the time.

Here's what I have done:

(p ∨ (q ∧ ¬r)) → p

¬(p ∨ (q ∧ ¬r)) ∨ p        Implication

¬(p) ∧ ¬(q ∧ ¬r)) ∨ p      De Morgan’s Laws

¬(p) ∧ (¬q ∨ ¬¬r) ∨ p      De Morgan’s Laws

¬(p) ∧ (¬q ∨ r) ∨ p        Double Negation

then I have no idea  what to continue.

Comment: To make this a bit easier to parse, we can note that $s:=q\wedge \neg r\implies \neg s = \neg q \vee r$. As such, the claim to be proven is that $$((p\vee s)\implies p)\iff p\wedge \neg s.$$ So that reduces the number of predicates by one.

Comment: With three variables, I would make a truth table.  It is only eight lines.  Alternately, assume $\not p$ and prove $\not q \vee r$ looks straightforward.

Comment: Also, there's a few missing parentheses as written which make the above work ambiguous. For instance, the last expression should read as $(\neg p \wedge (\neg q\vee r))\vee p$

Comment: Use Distributive law and Negation law, then it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the properties of the logical operators involved, we deduce the proposed equivalence:

\begin{align*}
(p\vee(q\wedge\neg r))\to p & \Longleftrightarrow \neg(p\vee(q\wedge\neg r))\vee p\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\wedge\neg(q\wedge\neg r))\vee p\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\wedge(\neg q\vee r))\vee p\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee p)\wedge(p\vee\neg q\vee r)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow p\vee\neg q\vee r
\end{align*}

where we have made use of the equivalence
\begin{align*}
P\to Q \Longleftrightarrow \neg P\vee Q
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: For comparison with the OP's progress, the crucial additional step is the use of the distributive property $(A\wedge B)\vee C=(A\vee C)\wedge (A\vee B)$.